# asp url routing doesn't work live

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using URL routing in an asp.net application similar to this article here https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx but a little different because I don't need any dynamic URL's they are all static.

my global.asax.cs has the following:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //register route for toolbox
        routes.MapPageRoute("Toolbox", "toolbox", "~/Default.aspx");

        //register route for aboutus
        routes.MapPageRoute("About Us", "about-us", "~/About.aspx");

        //register route for talktous
        routes.MapPageRoute("Talk To Us", "talk-to-us", "~/Contact.aspx");
    }
```

This works perfectly on my local machine, however when I add this to a dev server it breaks and returns 404 error. My local host URL of http://localhost:####/toolbox works fine, but on the server I upload this to the URL of http://##.##.##.##/toolbox returns a 404 error.
Any idea what might be causing that error?

Comment: Please consider posting what you changed in IIS to make this work. I have the same problem and would love to know how yo fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My money is on an IIS configuration on your dev server. WHat version of IIS are you running?

Comment: @j00b out of curiosity, what did you have to reconfigure?